# Default arguments within a Redux action creator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, immutability

Are there any unwanted sideeffects of having default arguments to an *action creator*? Or even using `Object.assign` within an action creator?

For example we have an action creator called `notify()` that creates notices in our store.

Although we need default arguments to these notices, we have a seperate function called `createNotice` that takes care of this.

Our action create looks like this:

```
export function notify(notification) {
  return {
    type: ADD,
    notification,
  };
}
```

And our `createNotice` looks like this:

```
export function createNotice(title = '', message, level = 'info', settings = {}) {
  return merge({}, {
    title,
    message,
    key: (new Date).getTime(),
    action: 'Dismiss',
    dismissAfter: 5000,
    className: level,
  }, settings);
}
```

I *really* dislike having to import `createNotice` and `notify` plus bind `notify` to dispatch for every component that uses it to do the following:

```
<Button onClick={() => nofity(createNotice('Something Happened', 'I think it worked!'))} />
```

Id rather something like the following:

```
<Button onClick={() => nofity('Something Happened', 'I think it worked!')} />
```

through having an action creator as such:

```
export function notify(notice) {
  return {
    type: ADD,
    createAction(notice),
  };
}
```

But that feels like a redux anti-pattern to me?

Answer (score 0):

Your `createNotice` function really is just a helper function for `notify`.

Your first approach makes no sense to me as your component does not need to be aware of `createNotice`.

Your second approach is what I would do. However you may want to spread the `...createNotice(notice)` or give it a name